# React - Display State Object Value in a Simple <div>

Tags: reactjs, object, state, key-value

All I want to do is to display a value from my state object in a div but I am having trouble figuring out how.

```
class MarketIndices extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:
        average: 426.661
        close: 427.11
        date: "2020-10-02,
    };
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
           """Inset how to display state object value here"""
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do I display something like the value of average in a div? It seems like it should be simple but I cannot figure it out!

Comment: <div>
          {this.state.data.average}
      </div>

Comment: [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

this code below.

```
class MarketIndices extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        average: 426.661,
        close: 427.11,
        date: "2020-10-02,
       }
    };
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
           {this.state.data.average}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```